# Left and Right camera according to ROS/OpenCV

Tags: calibration, ros-kinetic, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,

I am currently trying to calibrate 2 cameras (stereo calibration) and tried using [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration).

**Question**:
What is the Translation (and Rotation) vector in the output of the calibration ?
Is it  the transform required to move left camera coordinate system to right ?

**What I dont understand:**
The tutorial mentions left and right camera, but are these left and right wrt to user ?
(can be opposite since user is facing the cameras).

On digging deeper into openCV docs , I came across this image. It clearly suggests that the camera to the **right** of the user (facing cameras) is the **left** camera. However my results from stereo calibration dont make sense then.
Can someone please explain which is the left camera ??

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283786/left-and-right-camera-according-to-ros/opencv/) by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2018-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update from comments by @malharjajoo:

[Camera info](http://wiki.ros.org/image_pipeline/CameraInfo) parameters are described and illustrated at that link.

You can see some illustrations at [stereo_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc) that show left and right are with respect to the cameras, not to any external reference frame such as an observer.

From [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) the projection matrices are P1 and P2 as described in [cv::stereoRectify()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereorectify),
`P = [K | [Tx 0 0]'`.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2018-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-02-26**:
Hi, thanks a lot for answering... I'd like to point out, from the same [openCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html), the cv::stereoRectify() function mentions that P2 (for right camera) 4th coloumn contains by Tx * f (not Tx).

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-02-26**:
regardless of the scaled value, this Translation is negative. How is that correct ? shouldnt the right camera be positively translated since openCVs coordinate system has postive x-axis to the right.

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-02-26**:
I think rectification matrix given as output on [camera calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration) is the R1 and R2 from OpenCV docs. Hence rotation is not part of P1 and P2 ( P is not `R | t` , but instead `K | [ Tx 0 0 ]'`  as indicated in cv:stereoRectify().

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2018-02-26**:
P1 and P2 do seem to be described in [cv::stereoRectify](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereorectify). Since the right camera has the x-axis pointing to the right you have to translate along the negative x axis to get to the left camera

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-02-27**:
ok yeah, that makes sense. For some reason I was assuming the transform provided were from left to right coordinate system.

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-02-28**:
Hi, I have found a reference in the ROS wiki :D !  - [See last para](http://wiki.ros.org/image_pipeline/CameraInfo)

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-02-28**:
Also, @Thomas D, thanks for your help. Although a bit unrelated, I have been able to obtain a point cloud image using the stereo_image_proc using 2 cheap webcams. The point cloud gets very bad if the cameras are interchanged and hence this post helped me in that way too :D. cheers!